# @Url.Content in separate javascript file using ASPNET MVC 3 and Razor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-markers

I was using this

```
if (ret = 1)
    iconType = new google.maps.MarkerImage('@Url.Content("~/Content/images/image.png")');
else if (ret = 2)
    iconType = new google.maps.MarkerImage('@Url.Content("~/Content/images/image2.png")');
else if (ret = 3)
    iconType = new google.maps.MarkerImage('@Url.Content("~/Content/images/image3.png")');
```

in a View (ASPNET MVC 3), now I'm moving the code to a separate javascript file (I'm using that because depending on a vaiable value I set as image of a control image.png, image2.png or image3.png).

Razor doesn't parse @Url.Content inside javascript file, What's the best way to handle this?

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I usually put a block like this in the beginning of the page:

```
<script>
    var ROOT = '@Url.Content("~")';
</script>
```

And then i refer to the `ROOT` variable in javascript:

```
if (ret = 1)
    iconType = new google.maps.MarkerImage(ROOT + '/Content/images/image.png');
else if (ret = 2)
    iconType = new google.maps.MarkerImage(ROOT + '/Content/images/image2.png');
else if (ret = 3)
    iconType = new google.maps.MarkerImage(ROOT + '/Content/images/image3.png")');
```

Comment: Nice idea! Thanks! I improvised this by creating the script using a html helper, as my scripts have to be injected in to multiple layouts, thanks again!

Comment: "~/" already ends with a "/" -- if you add those two together you'll end up with "//" at the beginning of your URLs.  It should still work, but it's more graceful to just type (ROOT + 'Content/Images/Image.png');

Comment: How would you do this for a css image?

Answer (score 8):

Another solution is rendering your JS files completely through the RazorViewEngine. This way you could easily use the Razor Syntax within your Javascript file:

```
public class CustomRazorViewEngine : BuildManagerViewEngine
{
    internal static readonly string ViewStartFileName = "_ViewStart";

    public CustomRazorViewEngine()
        : this(null)
    {
    }

    public CustomRazorViewEngine(IViewPageActivator viewPageActivator)
        : base(viewPageActivator)
    {
        AreaViewLocationFormats = new[]
                                    {
                                        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                                        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
                                        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.csjs",
                                        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                                        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
                                        "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.csjs"
                                    };
        AreaMasterLocationFormats = new[]
                                        {
                                            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                                            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
                                            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.csjs",
                                            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                                            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
                                            "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.csjs"
                                        };
        AreaPartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
                                            {
                                                "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                                                "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
                                                "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.csjs",
                                                "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                                                "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
                                                "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.csjs"
                                            };

        ViewLocationFormats = new[]
                                {
                                    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                                    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
                                    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.csjs",
                                    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                                    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
                                    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.csjs"
                                };
        MasterLocationFormats = new[]
                                    {
                                        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                                        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
                                        "~/Views/{1}/{0}.csjs",
                                        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                                        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
                                        "~/Views/Shared/{0}.csjs"
                                    };
        PartialViewLocationFormats = new[]
                                        {
                                            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml",
                                            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.vbhtml",
                                            "~/Views/{1}/{0}.csjs",
                                            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml",
                                            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.vbhtml",
                                            "~/Views/Shared/{0}.csjs"
                                        };

        FileExtensions = new[]
                            {
                                "cshtml",
                                "vbhtml",
                                "csjs",
                            };
    }

    protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
        return new RazorView(controllerContext, partialPath,
                             layoutPath: null, runViewStartPages: false, viewStartFileExtensions: FileExtensions,
                             viewPageActivator: ViewPageActivator);
    }

    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        var view = new RazorView(controllerContext, viewPath,
                                 layoutPath: masterPath, runViewStartPages: true, viewStartFileExtensions: FileExtensions,
                                 viewPageActivator: ViewPageActivator);
        return view;
    }
}
```

In Your Global asax file just add these:

```
RazorCodeLanguage.Languages.Add("csjs", new CSharpRazorCodeLanguage());
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomRazorViewEngine());
```

And add this mapping in the web.config root

```
   <system.web>
          <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
                 <assemblies>
                       <add assembly="Newtonsoft.Json" />
                       <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                       <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                       <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                       <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                       <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                 </assemblies>

                 <!--Added-->
                 <buildProviders>
                       <add extension=".csjs" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.RazorBuildProvider, System.Web.WebPages.Razor"/>
                 </buildProviders>
```

You can now even work with a Model inside your javascript file!

```
public ActionResult MyJavascriptThroughRazor()
{
    var someModel = ...
    return PartialView("filenamewithcsjsextension",someModel);
}
```

Comment: This I think is a better solution. The only downside I see here is that the custom file format won't get good syntax support from the IDE. Yet, that could be customized...