# @Url.Content isn't found in my javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have the next line in my javascript file:

```
"<img alt=\"Active\" src=\"@Url.Content(\"~/Images/play.png\")\" />"
```

so I tried to do what `AHM` suggested in this topic ([@Url.Content in separate javascript file using ASPNET MVC 3 and Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663486/url-content-in-separate-javascript-file-using-aspnet-mvc-3-and-razor)):

```
var ROOT = "@Url.Content(\"~/";
"<img alt=\"Active\" src=\"" + ROOT + "Images/play.png\")\" />"
```

but I got an error:

```
Reports/@Url.Content( 404 (Not Found)
```

what I did wrong?

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Url.Content` is not supported in JavaScript file

In your code is wrong

```
var ROOT = "@Url.Content(\"~/"; <= parentheses is not closed & you donot need to escape quotes
```

Instead use in beginning of file

```
var ROOT = '@Url.Content("~/")';
```

Comment: I am sorry but It doesn't work..
var ROOT = '@Url.Content("~/")';

"<img alt=\"Active\" src=\"" + ROOT + "Images/play.png\")\" />";