# @Url.Content with external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using `blueimp upload` library. I have upload code in different `javascript` file. I am using `ASP.Net MVC`. I want to get root of my application through `Url.Content("~")` or something else (if any). I tried [this amswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663486/url-content-in-separate-javascript-file-using-aspnet-mvc-3-and-razor) but it's giving me literal '@Url.Content("~")' as a result. So I thought to use `data-*` of html. Now my file upload looks like

```
 <input type="file" name="files[]" data-root ='<%= @Url.Content("~/") %>' multiple/>
```

and upload code is

```
$('input:file', subscriber).fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                url: $(this).data('root')+'ControllerName/ActionName',
                done: function (e, data) {
                    if (!data || !data.result || !data.result.length) {
                        alert("Error occured when uploading the file");
                        return;
                    }

                    if (data.result[0].error) {
                        alert("Error occured. " + data.result[0].error);
                        return;
                    }

                    LoadHtmlInDiv('AssigneeDocList', '/Assignee/DocumentList');
                },
                fail: function (e, data) {
                    alert("Error occured when uploading the file");
                }
            });
```

but it's giving `Error 404` because new url is like

`/ProjectName/ControllerName/undefinedControllerName/ActionName`

I tried to check value of the same in `fail` callback, it's proper. Don't know why it's wrong with making url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming your `<input/>` tag is inside a form. If so, you can just pass empty string as `url`. `blueimp upload` upload uses the `form`'s `action` method url as base and appends its own url part to it. That why you are getting url like this

```
/ProjectName/ControllerName/undefinedControllerName/ActionName
```

In my own code I declared my form like -

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Document", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

and my `input` tag was inside it like -

```
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" />
```

and javascript -

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: '',
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {},
    done: function (e, data) {},
    progressall: function (e, data) {}
});
```

I have removed the function implementations, but you can get the idea. This post the file to

```
/Document/Upload
```

Comment: I have nested form, and it is finding parent form's action instead of closest  form action

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to nest `form` tags. Isn't there any way to place them separately?